# Drawing on an image using Swing

Tags: swing, drawing, jlabel, graphics2d

In one of the screens in my application, a few images are shown. All I want to do is to frame with a black line the image that the user has clicked on. Basically, I want to emphasize the chosen image. The black frame is just one of many ideas. You are welcome to suggest more efficient ideas.

I'm using NetBeans if it matters.

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: What is your question?  As an aside, no it does not matter what the code editor is.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. All I know is that I have to use Graphics2D, Swing is new for me. Since this issue is common, maybe someone has a good reference to code or tutorial of how to use Graphics2D. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to do this (if i get you right) is to subclass JComponent and overwrite the paint method.

take a look on the
[Reflection example](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/java2dtutorial/java2dimages/) on this site.

good sources for swing: 
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/category/package/swing/
http://javagraphics.blogspot.com/
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/java2dtutorial/java2dimages/
and the best:
http://filthyrichclients.org/

Comment: I disagree that extending JComponent is either best or necessary.  A JLabel can contain the image.  Add a MouseListener to detect clicks and change the JLabel border using a LineBorder.  +1 for the links, though.

Comment: Nice idea! Changing Label's boarder... Instead of painting on it. Thanks!